# I can't see sprites-diffuse shader im my assets

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to select "Sprites-diffuse" shader for a better performance in my project. The mostly and frequently rendered background gameplay objects with an alpha channel causes performance loss as you know.

As you can see
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DT408.png) there isn't a "Sprites-Diffuse" Shader material.

I couldn't find anywhere how to solve this or why this occurs. Many thanks to helping hands in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **create** a new `Material` which has a `Sprites-Diffuse` shader.

Right-click in the `Assets` windows, select `Create -> Material` and give it a name.

Then select it, go to the Inspector, click on the `Shader` drop-down menu and select `Sprites -> Diffuse`.

Now you can use this newly created material on any sprite you want.